# Why a new Row is added when clicking on dynamically created checkbox column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having a datagridview created as follows on button click

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns.Contains("column1") && dataGridView1.Columns.Contains("chk"))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            //chk.ReadOnly = true;
            chk.Name = "chk";
            chk.DisplayIndex = 0;
            chk.Frozen = true;  
            chk.HeaderText = "check";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk);
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            column1.ReadOnly = true;
            column1.Name = "column1";
            column1.HeaderText = "my column  name";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column1);
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            column2.ReadOnly = true;
            column2.Name = "column2";
            column2.HeaderText = "my column  name1";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column2);
        }
    }
```

But when i click on check box a ROW is created automatically why is it happening..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because the property `AllowUserToAddRows` is true by default.

set

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

and after adding columns. add a new row to dataGridView1

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

Comment: Small hep if i click on check box i would like to select that particular ROW can u tell me how